# How would be a functional approach to shifting certain array elements?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I have a Scala app with a list of items with checkboxes so the user select some, and click a button to shift them one position up (left). I decided to write a function to shift elements of some arbitrary type which meet a given predicate. So, if you have these elements:

```
a b c D E f g h I
```

and the predicate is "uppercase characters", the function would return this:

```
a b D E c f g I h
```

In short, any sequence of contiguous elements that meet the predicate are swapped with the single element at the left of it.

I came up with the following ugly imperative implementation. I would like to see a nice, and hopefully readable, functional solution.

```
def shiftUp[T](a:Array[T], shiftable: T => Boolean) = {
    val s = new Array[T](a.length)
    var i = 0
    var j = 0
    while(i < a.length)
    {
        if(!shiftable(a(i)) && i < a.length - 1 && shiftable(a(i+1)))
        {
            var ii = i + 1
            while(ii < a.length && shiftable(a(ii)))
            {
                s(j) = a(ii)
                ii = ii+1
                j = j+1
            }
            s(j) = a(i)
            i = ii
        }
        else
        {
            s(j) = a(i)
            i = i+1
        }
        j = j+1
    }
    s
}
```

EDIT: Thanks all, I hope you have enjoyed the exercise!

Comment: What do you want to see happen if the selection to shift is `A b C d`?

Comment: A C b d
The ones that reach the "top" simply stay there.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's a purely functional implementation

```
def shiftElements[A](l: List[A], pred: A => Boolean): List[A] = {
  def aux(lx: List[A], accum: List[A]): List[A] = {
    lx match {
      case Nil => accum
      case a::b::xs if pred(b) && !pred(a) => aux(a::xs, b::accum)
      case x::xs => aux(xs, x::accum)
    }
  }
  aux(l, Nil).reverse
}
```

And here's one that uses mutability on the inside to be faster

```
import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer
def shiftElements2[A](l: List[A], pred: A => Boolean): List[A] = {
  val buf = new ListBuffer[A]
  def aux(lx: List[A]) {
    lx match {
      case Nil => ()
      case a::b::xs if pred(b) && !pred(a) => {
        buf.append(b)
        aux(a::xs)
      }
      case x::xs => {
        buf.append(x)
        aux(xs)
      }
    }
  }
  aux(l)
  buf.toList
}
```

Comment: With scala 2.8 you can add @tailrec to optimise a bit your tail recusive function:  @tailrec def aux(...)

Comment: The functions are made tail recursive even without the annotation. The @tailrec annotation serves as an assertion that the function is intended be tail recursive and an error should be issued if TCO cannot be applied

Comment: What is the difference in performance between your pure functional and your mutable implementation?

Comment: I haven't measured the performance difference. Asymptotically they're both O(n) but the second doesn't need to reverse the results and probably has less allocation and creates less garbage.

Comment: It doesn't work correctly for a sequence starting with `pred(a)` true.

Answer (score 6):

You could probably do this via a `foldLeft` (also known as `/:`):

```
(str(0).toString /: str.substring(1)) { (buf, ch) =>
    if (ch.isUpper) buf.dropRight(1) + ch + buf.last  else buf + ch
}
```

It needs work to handle the empty String but:

```
def foo(Str: String)(p: Char => Boolean) : String = (str(0).toString /: str.substring(1)) { 
   (buf, ch) => if (p(ch) ) buf.dropRight(1) + ch + buf.last else buf + ch
}

val pred = (ch: Char) => ch.isUpper
foo("abcDEfghI")(pred) //prints abDEcfgIh
```

I'll leave it as an exercise as to how to modify this into the array-based solution

Comment: I like it, thanks... +1 because I can't accept more than 1 answer :)

Answer (score 2):

This is basically an imperative algorithm with a functional style.

```
def shifWithSwap[T](a: Array[T], p: T => Boolean) = {
  def swap(i:Int, j:Int) = {
    val tmp = a(i); a(i) = a(j); a(j) = tmp
  }
  def checkAndSwap(i:Int) = i match {
    case n if n < a.length - 1 && !p(a(i)) && p(a(i+1)) => swap(i, i+1)
    case _ =>
  }
  (0 until a.length - 1) map checkAndSwap
  a
}
```

It modifies the Array in place, with a side effect. I think it really does it like the version in the question, except it's easier to read. Imperative does not have to be ugly...

**Edit:** darn, couldn't fall asleep until I wrote this down (same as above, just more compact):

```
def shift[T](a: Array[T], p: T => Boolean) = {
  for (i <- 0 until a.length - 1; if !p(a(i)) && p(a(i+1))) {
    val tmp = a(i); a(i) = a(i+1); a(i+1) = tmp // swap
  }
  a
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not the fastest, but not limited to String and using the same logic as @oxbow_lakes

```
def shift[T](iter: Iterable[T])(p: T=>Boolean): Iterable[T] = 
  iter.foldLeft(Iterable[T]())((buf, elm) => 
    if (p(elm) && buf.nonEmpty) 
      buf.dropRight(1) ++ Iterable[T](elm) ++ Iterable[T](buf.last) 
    else 
      buf++Iterable[T](elm)
  )

def upperCase(c:Char)=c.isUpper

shift("abcDEfghI")(upperCase).mkString
    //scala> res86: String = abDEcfgIh

val array="abcDEfghI".toArray
shift(array)(upperCase).toArray
    //res89: Array[Char] = Array(a, b, D, E, c, f, g, I, h)

def pair(i:Int)=i%2==0
val l=List(1,2,3,5,4,6,7,9,8)
shift(l)(pair)
    //scala> res88: Iterable[Int] = List(2, 1, 3, 4, 6, 5, 7, 8, 9)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't claim this stuff below to be efficient or readable. Unfortunately, all the good answers seem to be taken, so I'm going for originality. :-)

```
def shift[T](a: Seq[T], p: T => Boolean) = {
  val (areP, notP) = a.zipWithIndex partition { case (t, index) => p(t) }
  val shifted = areP map { case (t, index) => (t, index - 1) }
  val others = notP map (shifted.foldLeft(_){
    case ((t, indexNotP), (_, indexIsP)) => 
      if (indexNotP == indexIsP) (t, indexNotP + 1) else (t, indexNotP)
  })
  (shifted ++ others).sortBy(_._2).map(_._1)
}
```

So, here's what's happening. First, I associate each character with its index (`a.zipWithIndex`), and then separate then into `areP` and `notP` depending on whether the character satisfies `p` or not.

So, at this point, I have two sequences, each composed of a character and its index in the original sequence.

Next, I simply shift the index of the elements in the first sequence, by subtracting 1, and compute `shifted`.

Computing the new index of the unshifted elements is much harder. For each of those elements (`notP map`), I'll do a `foldLeft`. The accumulator of the fold left will be the element itself (always with its index). The sequence that is being folded is the sequence of shifted elements -- so one can see that for each unshifted element, I traverse the whole sequence of shifted elements (highly inefficient!).

So, we compare the index of the unshifted element to the index of each shifted element. If they are equal, increase the index of the unshifted element. Because the sequence of shifted elements is ordered (`partition` doesn't change the order), we know that we'll test first for lower indices, and then for higher indices, guaranteeing that an element will have its index increased as much as necessary.

With that, we join the two sequences, order them by their new indices, and then map back to the element.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another variant on Geoff's answer:

```
def shift[T](l: List[T], p: T => Boolean): List[T] = {
  l match {
    case a::b::t if ! p(a) && p(b) => b::shift(a::t, p)
    case a::t => a::shift(t, p)
    case Nil => l
  }
}
```

Quickly tested using

```
scala> def pred(c: Char) = c.isUpper
pred: (c: Char)Boolean

scala> shift("abcDEfghI".toList, pred)
res3: List[Char] = List(a, b, D, E, c, f, g, I, h)

scala> shift("AbCd".toList, pred)
res4: List[Char] = List(A, C, b, d)

scala> shift(Nil, pred)
res5: List[Nothing] = List()
```

Here's version two

```
def shift[T](l: List[T], p: T => Boolean, r: List[T] = Nil): List[T] = {
  l match {
    case a::b::t if ! p(a) && p(b) => shift(a::t, p, b::r)
    case a::t => shift(t, p, a::r)
    case Nil => r.reverse
  }
}
```

Comment: Just realised this is flawed as it's not tail recursive

Answer (score 1):

I don't know enough to write it in Scala, but this problem is tailor-made for the list functions `takeWhile` and `dropWhile`.  The idea is that you split the list of items into three parts:

- Left part, computed with `takeWhile`, contains leftmost elements not satisfying the predicate.
- Middle part is the group of elements you want to shift left, computed by dropping the left elements and then `takeWhile` the remainder.
- Right part is everything left over; `dropWhile` the middle elements.

Here it is in Haskell:

```
-- take first group of elements satisfying p and shift left one
shift :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
shift p l = case reverse left of 
              []     -> l
              (a:as) -> reverse as ++ middle ++ a : shift p right
  where left    = takeWhile (not . p) l  -- could be done with List.break
        notLeft = dropWhile (not . p) l
        middle  = takeWhile p notLeft    -- could be done with List.span
        right   = dropWhile p notLeft
```

And here's a single unit test:

```
*Shiftup> shift (>9) [1, 2, 3, 44, 55, 6, 7, 8]
[1,2,44,55,3,6,7,8]
```

Haskell programmers might use `List.break` or `List.span` to combine calls to `takeWhile` and `dropWhile`, but I'm not sure if Scala has these things.  Besides, `takeWhile` and `dropWhile` are nice meaningful names, whereas I at least find `break` and `span` less perspicuous.

**EDIT**: fixed recursive call to do `shift p right` instead of `right` to shift up all groups.

Comment: Nice code, but I think we're supposed to shift all of the groups satisfying p. I think that'd be done by changing ": right" to ": shift  p right".

Comment: The takeWhile/dropWhile pairs could be coded with span or break, also, though maybe this'd be less clear to someone unfamiliar with Haskell. (I just had to look it up myself -- I'm rusty.)

Comment: Yes, all the groups satisfying p should be shifted

Comment: Thanks, guys.  @Darius and @German, the code is fixed.  I added some commentary about `break` and `span`.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: this doesn't actually solve the posed problem--it solves a related but different problem (bumping up the priority of marked items by one).  I'm leaving it here for reference, however.

---

Here's a "one-liner", using arrays as requested, for Scala 2.8.

```
def shiftUp[T](a: Array[T], p: T => Boolean) = {
  a.zipWithIndex.map(ci => {
    (ci._1 , if (p(ci._1)) ci._2 - 1.5 else ci._2.toDouble)
  }).sortWith((l,r) => l._2 < r._2).map(_._1)
}

scala> shiftUp(Array('h','E','l','l','O'),(c:Char)=>c.isUpper).toArray
res0: Array[Char] = Array(E, h, l, O, l)

scala> shiftUp("HeLlO".toArray,(c:Char)=>c.isUpper).toArray
res1: Array[Char] = Array(H, L, e, O, l)
```

I leave it as an exercise to the reader to figure out how it works.  (If you really want generics with T, in Scala 2.8 it's going to give you an GenericArray; you then can toArray it if you want a Java potentially-primitive array.)

Comment: It does not seem to shift the last letter on `Array('h','e','l','L','O')`.

Comment: The problem as you describe it sounds to me just like the one I posted (bumping up priority by one = shifting one to the left). How exactly do the problems differ?

Comment: They differ depending on the rightward moves.  In my algorithm, those that "stay behind" move one space right.  In yours, those that "stay behind" move one _block_ right, where a block may be many contiguous letters.

Answer (score 0):

A solution in J:

```
   ('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ') (4 : '(y#~y e. >1{x)([: I. '' ''= ])} }._1&|.&.((1,~y e. >0{x)&#)y,'' ''') 'abcDEfghI'
abDEcfgIh
```

Let’s break this into named pieces for easier comprehension.  The final string “`abDEcfgIh`” is the result of applying a function to the string “`abcDEfghI`” which is the right argument to the function.  The pair of alphabets constitute the left argument to the function (which is the part beginning “(`4 :`…”).  So, instead of the 2-element vector of boxed strings, we could name each one individually:

```
   'lc uc'=. 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
```

Now that we have two variables “`lc`” and “`uc`”  for the lower-case and upper-case alphabets, let’s examine the body of the function in detail.  Taking a logically coherent chunk from the right end, since this would be evaluated first, we could name this like so:

```
   rmUCshift=: 4 : 0
   }._1&|.&.((1,~y e. >0{x)&#)y,' '
)
```

This defines “`rmUCshift`” as something that requires a right and left argument (the “`4 :`” specifies this) with the body beginning on the next line and continuing to the bare closing paren.  The “`4 : 0`” form, followed by the body, is a variant of the “`4 :`‘body’” form shown initially.  This verb `rmUCshift` can be invoked independently like this:

```
   (lc;'') rmUCshift 'abcDEfghI'  NB. Remove upper-case, shift, then insert
ab  cfg h                         NB. spaces where the upper-case would now be.
```

The invocation is indented three spaces and the output immediately follows the it.  The left argument `(lc;'')` is a two-element vector with the empty array specified as the second element because it’s not used in this piece of the code – we could have used any value after the semicolon but the two single quotes are easy to type.

The next pieces to name are these (definitions followed by examples):

```
  ixSpaces=: [:I.' '=]
  ixSpaces 'ab  cfg h'
2 3 7
   onlyUC=: 4 : 'y#~y e.>1{x'
   ('';uc) onlyUC 'abcDEfghI'
DEI
```

Combining these named pieces together gives us this:

```
   (lc;uc) (4 : '(x onlyUC y)(ixSpaces x rmUCshift y)}x rmUCshift y') 'abcDEfghI'
abDEcfgIh
```

However, the repetition of “`x rmUCshift y`” is unnecessary and can be simplified to give us this:

```
   (lc;uc) (4 : '(x onlyUC y) ((ixSpaces ]) } ]) x rmUCshift y') 'abcDEfghI'
abDEcfgIh
```