# cannot find class manifest for element type T

Tags: scala, scala-2.8

Was trying to compile some code from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2244885/how-would-be-a-functional-approach-to-shifting-certain-array-elements) and run into this error message `cannot find class manifest for element type T`. Here is another snippet that shows the behavior:

```
scala> def f[T](a:T, b:T):Array[T] = { new Array[T](2) }
<console>:4: error: cannot find class manifest for element type T
       def f[T](a:T, b:T):Array[T] = { new Array[T](2) }
```

I can see that `new collection.mutable.GenericArray[T](2)` fixes the issue. Apparently *providing a manifest* is the other option... But what does *"providing a manifest mean"*?

Comment: Note that GenericArray was renamed to ArraySeq in Scala 2.8 final.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To provide type information you can use a context bound

```
def f[T : Manifest](a:T, b:T):Array[T] = { new Array[T](2) }
```

or the manifest as an implicit argument:

```
def f[T](a:T, b:T)(implicit manifest : Manifest[T]) : Array[T] = { new Array[T](2) }
```

The former is syntactic sugar for the later. The [manifest](http://www.scala-blogs.org/2008/10/manifests-reified-types.html) is needed because the type information about T is missing due to generic [type errasure](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) of the JVM.

Comment: Some information is also given by Martin in this paper http://www.scala-lang.org/sites/default/files/sids/cunei/Thu,%202009-10-01,%2013:54/arrays.pdf

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3213510/what-is-a-manifest-in-scala-and-when-do-you-need-it for more on manifests and type erasure.

Comment: AFAIK ClassManifest is sufficient in this case.