# What is a Manifest in Scala and when do you need it?

Tags: scala, manifest

Since Scala 2.7.2 there is something called `Manifest` which is a workaround for Java's type erasure. But how does `Manifest` work exactly and why / when do you need to use it?

The blog post *[Manifests: Reified Types](http://www.scala-blogs.org/2008/10/manifests-reified-types.html)*  by Jorge Ortiz explains some of it, but it doesn't explain how to use it together with [context bounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2982276/what-is-a-context-bound-in-scala).

Also, what is `ClassManifest`, what's the difference with `Manifest`?

I have some code (part of a larger program, can't easily include it here) that has some warnings with regard to type erasure; I suspect I can solve these by using manifests, but I'm not sure exactly how.

Comment: There has been a discussion on the mailing list about the Manifest/ClassManifest difference, see http://scala-programming-language.1934581.n4.nabble.com/What-s-the-difference-between-ClassManifest-and-Manifest-td2125122.html

Comment: See also: [Scala: What is a TypeTag and how do I use it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12218641/scala-what-is-a-typetag-and-how-do-i-use-it)

Answer (score 205, accepted):

The compiler knows more information about types than the JVM runtime can easily represent.  A Manifest is a way for the compiler to send an inter-dimensional message to the code at runtime about the type information that was lost.

It isn't clear if a Manifest would benefit the errors you are seeing without knowing more detail.

One common use of Manifests is to have your code behave differently based on the static type of a collection.  For example, what if you wanted to treat a List[String] differently from other types of a List:

```
 def foo[T](x: List[T])(implicit m: Manifest[T]) = {
    if (m <:< manifest[String])
      println("Hey, this list is full of strings")
    else
      println("Non-stringy list")
  }
  
  foo(List("one", "two")) // Hey, this list is full of strings
  foo(List(1, 2)) // Non-stringy list
  foo(List("one", 2)) // Non-stringy list
```

A reflection-based solution to this would probably involve inspecting each element of the list.

A context bound seems most suited to using type-classes in scala, and is well explained here by Debasish Ghosh:
http://debasishg.blogspot.com/2010/06/scala-implicits-type-classes-here-i.html

Context bounds can also just make the method signatures more readable.  For example, the above function could be re-written using context bounds like so:

```
  def foo[T: Manifest](x: List[T]) = {
    if (manifest[T] <:< manifest[String])
      println("Hey, this list is full of strings")
    else
      println("Non-stringy list")
  }
```

Answer (score 26):

A Manifest was intended to reify generic types that get type-erased to run on the JVM (which does not support generics). However, they had some serious issues: they were too simplistic, and were unable to fully support Scala's type system. They were thus **deprecated** in Scala 2.10, and are replaced with `TypeTag`s (which are essentially what the Scala compiler itself uses to represent types, and therefore fully support Scala types). For more details on the difference, see:

- [Scala: What is a TypeTag and how do I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12218641/scala-2-10-what-is-a-typetag-and-how-do-i-use-it)
- [How do the new Scala TypeTags improve the (deprecated) Manifests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10513336/how-do-the-new-scala-typetags-improve-the-deprecated-manifests)

## In other words

> when do you need it?

Before 2013-01-04, [when Scala 2.10 was released](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/27499).

Comment: It's not yet deprecated (but will be), as Scala reflection is still experimental in 2.10.

Comment: Before 2013-01-04, or if you're using an API that relies on it.

Answer (score 25):

Not a complete answer, but regarding the difference between `Manifest` and `ClassManifest`, you can find an example in the [Scala 2.8 `Array` paper](http://www.scala-lang.org/sites/default/files/sids/cunei/Thu,%202009-10-01,%2013:54/arrays.pdf):

> The only remaining question is how to implement generic array creation. Unlike Java, Scala allows an instance creation new  `Array[T]` where `T` is a type parameter. How can this be implemented, given the fact that there does not exist a uniform array representation in Java?
>
> The only way to do this is to require additional runtime information which describes the type `T`. Scala 2.8 has a new mechanism for this, which is called a **Manifest**. An object of type `Manifest[T]` provides complete information about the type `T`.
>   `Manifest` values are typically passed in implicit parameters; and the compiler knows how to construct them for statically known types `T`.
>
> There exists also a **weaker form** named **`ClassManifest` which can be constructed from knowing just the top-level class of a type, without necessarily knowing all its argument types**.
>   It is this type of runtime information that’s required for array creation.

Example:

> One needs to provide this information by passing a `ClassManifest[T]` into the 
>   method as an implicit parameter:

```
def  tabulate[T](len:Int,  f:Int=>T)(implicit m:ClassManifest[T]) =  { 
  val  xs  =  new  Array[T](len) 
  for   (i  <- 0  until   len)  xs(i)   = f(i) 
  xs 
}
```

> As a shorthand form, a context bound1 can be used on the type parameter `T` instead,

(See this [SO question for illustration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2252641/cannot-find-class-manifest-for-element-type-t))

> , giving:

```
def  tabulate[T:    ClassManifest](len:Int,  f:Int=>T)  =  { 
  val  xs  =  new  Array[T](len) 
  for   (i  <- 0  until   len)  xs(i)   = f(i) 
  xs 
}
```

> When calling tabulate on a type such as `Int`, or `String`, or `List[T]`, the Scala compiler can create a class manifest to pass as implicit argument to tabulate.

Answer (score 1):

Let's also chck out `manifest` in `scala` sources (`Manifest.scala`), we see:

```
Manifest.scala:
def manifest[T](implicit m: Manifest[T])           = m
```

So with regards to following example code:

```
def foo[A](somelist: List[A])(implicit m: Manifest[A]): String = {
  if (m <:< manifest[String]) {
    "its a string"
  } else {
    "its not a string"
  }
}
```

we can see that the `manifest`  `function` searches for an implicit `m: Manifest[T]` which satisfies the `type parameter` you provide in our example code it was `manifest[String]`.  So when you call something like:

```
if (m <:< manifest[String]) {
```

you are checking if the current `implicit m` which you defined in your function is of type `manifest[String]` and as the `manifest` is a function of type `manifest[T]` it would search for a specific `manifest[String]` and it would find if there is such an implicit.