# About Scala generics: cannot find class manifest for element type T

Tags: generics, scala

For a function as below:

```
def reverse[T](a: Array[T]): Array[T] = {
    val b = new Array[T](a.length)
    for (i <- 0 until a.length)
        b(i) = a(a.length -i - 1)
    b
}
```

I am getting "error: cannot find class manifest for element type T" from line 2.

Is there anyway to solve this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Simply add a context bound [ClassManifest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3213510/what-is-a-manifest-in-scala-and-when-do-you-need-it) to your method declaration:

```
def reverse[T : ClassManifest](a: Array[T]): Array[T] = ...
```

In order to construct an array, the array's concrete type must be known at compile time. This type is supplied by the compiler via an implicit ClassManifest parameter. That is, the signature of the Array constructor is actually

```
Array[T](size: Int)(implicit m: ClassManifest[T]): Array[T]
```

In order to supply this parameter, there must be a ClassManifest in scope when the Array constructor is invoked. Therefore, your reverse method must also take an implicit ClassManifest parameter:

```
def reverse[T](a: Array[T])(implicit m: ClassManifest[T]): Array[T] = ...
// or equivalently
def reverse[T : ClassManifest](a: Array[T]): Array[T] = ...
```

The latter, simpler notation is called a [context bound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2982276/what-is-a-context-bound-in-scala).

Comment: One can use `Manifest` instead of `ClassManifest` in the context bound. What´s the difference?

Comment: Good question. Just trying to figure out the same thing myself :-)

Comment: It appears that Manifest is a type alias for scala.reflect.Manifest, which is not documented in the ScalaDoc (maybe because it's compiler magic?).  For that reason, I'd tend to prefer ClassManifest just for clarity

Comment: `ClassManifest` requires only that the compiler knows the class of the type. `Manifest` requires that the compiler knows all its type parameters too.  Eg. for `List[String]`, the former only needs knowledge of `List` whereas the latter needs `List[String]`. To create a Java array, you only need the former.

Comment: The ClassManifest vs Manifest question has been answered in more detail at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3213510/what-is-a-manifest-in-scala-and-when-do-you-need-it

Answer (score 2):

When using [T : ClassManifest] if it is shown as deprecated use [T : ClassTag]

Answer (score 0):

While declaring Generic Type parameter, following ways works:

- (T: ClassManifest), but it is shown deprecated in scala 2.11.
- (T: Manifest)
- (T: ClassTag), works without error, and looks like a perfect solution as the error given by compiler was:

> cannot find class tag for element type T

```
package com.github.sandip.adt

import scala.reflect.ClassTag

class QueueUsingArray[T](capacity: Int)(implicit m: ClassTag[T]) {
  var array = new Array[T](capacity)

  private var front = -1
  private var rare = -1

  def enqueue(data: T) = {
    array(rare + 1) = data
    rare += 1
  }

  def dequeue: T = {
    front += 1
    array(front)
  }

  def isEmpty() = {
    !nonEmpty
  }

  def nonEmpty: Boolean = {
    rare > front
  }

}

object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val queue = new QueueUsingArray[Int](10)
    queue.enqueue(10)
    queue.enqueue(20)
    while (queue.nonEmpty) {
      println(queue.dequeue)
    }
  }
}
```