# Getting the type of parametrization of an instance of a parametrized class in scala

Tags: scala, parameterization

Im quite new in Scala.
I need to get the parametrization of a class.
How can I do this ? the class looks like this:

```
   class OutPort[T](name: Symbol, owner: Component) extends Port[T](name)
```

i got many OutPorts in an LinkedList. In another class i want to get the parametrization of an instance of OutPort, but the parametrization is arbitrary and a solution with isInstanceOf is not capable. is there a special method for such purpose, which i didnt covered yet ?

Lunatikz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned before, you can use a ClassManifest or a manifest. Here's a use example :

```
class Foo[T](t: T)(implicit m: ClassManifest[T]) {
  def foo = m toString
}

scala> (new Foo(5)) foo
```

`   res1: java.lang.String = Int

```
scala> (new Foo("hi")) foo
res2: java.lang.String = java.lang.String

scala> (new Foo(new scala.swing.Frame)) foo
res3: java.lang.String = scala.swing.Frame
```

Here's some SO topics related to Scala's manifests :

[What is a Manifest in Scala and when do you need it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3213510/what-is-a-manifest-in-scala-and-when-do-you-need-it)

[How does Scala's (2.8) Manifest work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3587286/how-does-scalas-2-8-manifest-work)

[How do I get around type erasure on Scala? Or, why can't I get the type parameter of my collections?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094173/how-do-i-get-around-type-erasure-on-scala-or-why-cant-i-get-the-type-parameter)

Answer (score 5):

Keep a Manifest of the type, and use that. If you told us why you want to get that back, we might be able to answer the question better too.

Comment: I have to make a simulation framework, where i want to simulate behavior of some components. In this Framework, there is a gui, and i have to delegate values from the gui, to components.

Comment: components have Ports, which are parametrized with a special type. When I get the inputs from gui, i have strings or ints and have to box them in another type, which has a field data of type any, to store data of any type. the type of field data must be arbitrary. then i can send the boxed item to an component which have to delegate this to its outport. a component can have many outports for different types. when i got the data and it is a Int for example, i want to determine the Port with the int parametrisation. the framework must deal with generated scala files

Comment: where the datatypes used are arbitrary and in consequence to me unknown. Im sorry for my pssibly bad english

Comment: @lunatikz - you can edit your question to provide more detail - easier to read than lots of comments! :-)

Comment: If you have a GUI you probably have dynamic configuration of ports and connections, and won't have any use for the type parameter anyway.