# Scala expected exception snippet

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, type-erasure

I'm trying to simulate the expected exception behavior of common testing frameworks (e.g. JUnit or TestNG).

Here's what I could come up with so far (working):

```
trait ExpectAsserts
{
  self : {
    def fail (message : String)
    def success (message : String)
  } =>

  def expect[T](exceptionClass : Class[T])(test : => Unit)
  {
    try
    {
      test
      fail("exception not thrown")
    }
    catch
    {
      case expected : T => success("got exception " + expected)
      case other : Exception => fail("expected "+ exceptionClass + " but " + other + " thrown instead.")
    }
  }
}

object Main extends ExpectAsserts
{
  def main (args : Array[String])
  {
    expect(classOf[ArithmeticException])
    {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException // this should print an error message.
    }
  }

  def fail (s : String)
  {
    System.err.println(s)
  }

  def success(s : String)
  {
    System.out.println(s)
  }
}
```

The snippet has a `main` method that exercises the code. My problem is that the exception thrown enters in the first pattern matching statement:

```
case expected : T
```

Although I'm actually saying that the exception has to be of type `T`, which would be `IllegalArgumentException`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Compile with `-unchecked` and you'll see a warning that the type test `expected: T` will *always* return true, thanks to type erasure.

```
scala> def foo[T](a: Any) = a match { 
     |    case _: T => "always will match!"
     | }
<console>:22: warning: abstract type T in type pattern T is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure
          case _: T => "always will match!"
                  ^
foo: [T](a: Any)java.lang.String

scala> foo[String](0)
res3: java.lang.String = always will match!
```

Seeing as you have the class passed in you can use `Class#isInstance` instead. In your code, that would look like:

```
case expected if clazz.isInstance(expected) => success("got exception " + expected)
```

In a self contained example. Here we pass a `Manifest[T]` implicitly, which is a way to get the compiler to pass an extra parameter to obtain the information that type erasure threw away:

```
scala> def foo[T: ClassManifest](a: Any) = manifest[T].erasure.isInstance(a)
foo: [T](a: Any)(implicit evidence$1: Manifest[T])Boolean

scala> foo[String](new {})  // compiler passes Manifest[String] here
res4: Boolean = false

scala> foo[String]("")
res5: Boolean = true
```

Further reading:

- [How do I get around type erasure on Scala? Or, why can't I get the type parameter of my collections?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094173/how-do-i-get-around-type-erasure-on-scala-or-why-cant-i-get-the-type-parameter)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1332574/common-programming-mistakes-for-scala-developers-to-avoid/1338119#1338119
- [What is a Manifest in Scala and when do you need it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3213510/what-is-a-manifest-in-scala-and-when-do-you-need-it)
- Specs2 [Exception Matchers](https://github.com/etorreborre/specs2/blob/1.6/src/main/scala/org/specs2/matcher/ExceptionMatchers.scala#L16)