# Create a method that receives a type parameter but not as a parameter, just like classOf

Tags: scala, reflection

I have the following code:

```
class ServletSpec extends Specification {

    def createServlet[T <: HttpServlet](clazz: Class[T]): T = {

        val instance = clazz.newInstance()
        instance.init()

        instance

    }

}
```

That is called like this:

```
spec.createServlet( classOf[DocumentationServlet] )
```

How can I define this method so that I can call it like this:

```
spec.createServlet[DocumentationServlet]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using Manifests:

```
class ServletSpec extends Specification {
    def createServlet[T <: HttpServlet]()(implicit manifest: Manifest[T]) = {
        val instance = manifest.erasure.newInstance().asInstanceOf[T]
        instance.init()

        instance
    }
}

new ServletSpec().createServlet[DocumentationServlet]()
```

The implicit parameter is filled in by the compiler, and a Manifest contains the type information required to create a new instance. For more information, see [What is a Manifest in Scala and when do you need it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3213510/what-is-a-manifest-in-scala-and-when-do-you-need-it)

Comment: Not working for me, manifest.erasure is of Class[_] instead of Class[HttpServlet]. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Sorry, missed off the .asInstanceOf, see val instance line

Comment: Hum, so I have to cast the value to what I want as the manifest is not going to be of the exact type? Nice, thank you!