# How do the new Scala TypeTags improve the (deprecated) Manifests?

Tags: scala, type-erasure, scala-2.10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Scala 2.10: What is a TypeTag and how do I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12218641/scala-2-10-what-is-a-typetag-and-how-do-i-use-it)

I have been reading about the new TypeTags which come along with the new reflection api. It seems that Manifests are supposed to be replaced with that new concept. Can anyone post some code examples to show the benefits?

Some references:

- [TypeTags API](http://www.scala-lang.org/archives/downloads/distrib/files/nightly/docs/library/scala/reflect/api/TypeTags.html)
- [SIP: Self-cleaning macros](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1O879Iz-567FzVb8kw6N5OBpei9dnbW0ZaT7-XNSa6Cs/edit?pli=1)
- [Metaprogramming in Scala](http://scalamacros.org/talks/2012-04-28-MetaprogrammingInScala210.pdf)

Comment: This is interesting stuff but more of a mailing list question in its current formulation. At the very least add some links to what you've been reading.

Comment: This is my first question ever in StackOverflow, so can you tell me why do you think is not suitable in this context?

Comment: I have added the references. Thank you!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Manifests are a lie. It has no knowledge of variance (assumes all type parameters are co-variants), and it has no support for path-dependent, existential or structural types.

TypeTags are types *as the compiler understands them*. Not "like" the compiler understands them, but "as" the compiler understands them -- the compiler itself use TypeTags. It's not 1-to-1, it's just 1. :-)

Comment: I think that's a good way to see it.

Comment: This explanation made a lot more sense after understanding Manifests.

Comment: Actually, it's worse than that. Manifest is not even an exponential functor. This has pretty serious implications for APIs that use it, to the extent that it should never be used.

Comment: @TonyMorris - What's the consequence of Manifest's not being an exponential functor? I admit that I don't even know what that is. thanks

Comment: @KevinMeredith My guess is that it means that Manifests can't represent all types for any given type parameters.