# Match Value with Function based on Type

Tags: scala

Suppose I have a list of functions as so:

```
val funcList = List(func1: A => T, func2: B => T, func2: C => T)
```

(where `func1`, et al. are defined elsewhere)

I want to write a method that will take a value and match it to the right function based on exact type (match `a: A` with `func1: A => T`) or throw an exception if there is no matching function.

Is there a simple way to do this?

This is similar to what a `PartialFunction` does, but I am not able to change the list of functions in `funcList` to PartialFunctions. I am thinking I have to do some kind of implicit conversion of the functions to a special class that knows the types it can handle and is able to pattern match against it (basically promoting those functions to a specialized `PartialFunction`). However, I can't figure out how to identify the "domain" of each function.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual answer to work around type erasure is to use the help of manifests. In your case, you can do the following:

```
abstract class TypedFunc[-A:Manifest,+R:Manifest] extends (A => R) {
  val retType: Manifest[_] = manifest[R]
  val argType: Manifest[_] = manifest[A]
}
object TypedFunc {
  implicit def apply[A:Manifest, R:Manifest]( f: A => R ): TypedFunc[A, R] = {
    f match {
      case tf: TypedFunc[A, R]  => tf
      case _ => new TypedFunc[A, R] { final def apply( arg: A ): R = f( arg ) }
    }
  }
}

def applyFunc[A, R, T >: A : Manifest]( funcs: Traversable[TypedFunc[A,R]] )( arg: T ): R = {
  funcs.find{ f => f.argType <:< manifest[T] } match {
    case Some( f ) => f( arg.asInstanceOf[A] )
    case _ => sys.error("Could not find function with argument matching type " + manifest[T])
  }
}

val func1 = { s: String => s.length }
val func2 = { l: Long => l.toInt }
val func3 = { s: Symbol => s.name.length }
val funcList = List(func1: TypedFunc[String,Int], func2: TypedFunc[Long, Int], func3: TypedFunc[Symbol, Int])
```

Testing in the REPL:

```
scala> applyFunc( funcList )( 'hello )
res22: Int = 5
scala> applyFunc( funcList )( "azerty" )
res23: Int = 6
scala> applyFunc( funcList )( 123L )
res24: Int = 123
scala> applyFunc( funcList )( 123 )
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not find function with argument matching type Int
        at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
        at .applyFunc(<console>:27)
        at .<init>(<console>:14)
        ...
```

Comment: Very cool. Thanks for providing a concrete example using Manifests!

Comment: Yes. Although you should now (in 2.10) favour `TypeTag` over `Manifest`, but it does work.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot identify the domain of each function, because they are erased at runtime. Look up erasure if you want more information, but the short of it is that the information you want does not exist.

There are ways around type erasure, and you'll find plenty discussions on Stack Overflow itself. Some of them come down to storing the type information somewhere as a value, so that you can match on that.

Another possible solution is to simply forsake the use of parameterized types (*generics*  in Java parlance) for your own customized types. That is, doing something like:

```
abstract class F1 extends (A => T)
object F1 { 
  def apply(f: A => T): F1 = new F1 { 
    def apply(n: A): T = f(n) 
  } 
}
```

And so on. Since `F1` doesn't have type parameters, you can match on it, and you can create functions of this type easily. Say both `A` and `T` are `Int`, then you could do this, for example:

```
F1(_ * 2)
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel. Very interesting solution. Also: I like your blog. :)

Answer (score 2):

I think you're misunderstanding how a `List` is typed. `List` takes a single type parameter, which is the type of *all* the elements of the list. When you write

```
val funcList = List(func1: A => T, func2: B => T, func2: C => T)
```

the compiler will infer a type like `funcList : List[A with B with C => T]`.

This means that each function in `funcList` takes a parameter that is a member of *all of* `A`, `B`, and `C`.

Apart from this, you can't (directly) match on function types due to type erasure.

What you could instead do is match on `a` itself, and call the appropriate function for the type:

```
a match {
    case x : A => func1(x)
    case x : B => func2(x)
    case x : C => func3(x)
    case _ => throw new Exception
}
```

(Of course, `A`, `B`, and `C` must remain distinct after type-erasure.)

If you *need* it to be dynamic, you're basically using reflection. Unfortunately Scala's reflection facilities are in flux, with version 2.10 released a few weeks ago, so there's less documentation for the current way of doing it; see [How do the new Scala TypeTags improve the (deprecated) Manifests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10513336/how-do-the-new-scala-typetags-improve-the-deprecated-manifests).

Comment: I can make your suggestion because the ordering and number of the functions depends on the clients implementing the service. Your earlier note was really helpful, though, thanks.