# Casting after comparison of two Array manifest in scala

Tags: arrays, scala, casting, manifest

I have some problem to cast my objeсt `Variable[A]` where `A <: Array[_]`

I create a function to compare `manifest` and cast data into Array to the good type.

My object `Variable[A]` store a `Manifest[A]` into the def `'type'`

I make a plugin of an existent software, so it's not me which instanciate this `Variable` with good type.

Prototype object and class :

```
object Prototype {
  def apply[T](n: String)(implicit t: Manifest[T]) = new Prototype[T] {
    val name = n
    val `type` = t
  }
}

trait Prototype[T] {
  def name: String
  def `type`: Manifest[T]
}
```

Variable Object and Class :

```
object Variable {
  def apply[T](p: Prototype[T], v: T) = new Variable[T] {
    val prototype = p
    val value = v
  }
}

trait Variable[T] {
  def prototype: Prototype[T]
  def value: T
}
```

My class which use :

```
class XYDataReader[A <: Array[_]](var data: Iterable[Variable[A]]) {

    def get[T](variable: Variable[A])(implicit m: Manifest[T]): Option[T] = {
        if (variable.prototype.`type` <:< m) {
          Some(variable.value.asInstanceOf[T])
        } else {
          None
        } 
}
}
```

There is probably a mistake of my part when i instanciate Variable object used to compare, so i give also the code of instanciation :

```
val v:List[Any] = List[Any](1.2,2,3)
val p = Prototype[Array[Any]]("col1")
val myVariable = Variable(p, v.toArray(ClassTag(p.`type`.runtimeClass)))
```

I don't understand why pattern matching failed when i call `get[Array[Double]](myVariable)` where `myVariable.value` contain an `Array[Double]`

When i `println()` the two manifest :

- variable array type : `Array[double]`
- m type : `Array[Double]`

It seem an `Array[Double]` is not an `Array[double]`, how can i resolve/cast this ?

Comment: Keep in mind that Scala's `Array` is a JVM `Array` and they are _invariant_. Thus no two distinct `Array` types stand in the subtype relationship to each other.

Comment: I think the best suggestion would be to avoid `Array` for starters. Secondly, avoid casting, at least overtly. Scala pattern matching is a much better way of dealing with dynamic type decisions.

Comment: I try to use this approach in my code in reality : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3213510/what-is-a-manifest-in-scala-and-when-do-you-need-it ; but it work in the link probably because it use List and not Array ...

Comment: Another note: _All_ mutable collections (and `Array`) are _in_variant. Immutable structures are _co_variant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, with help of colleague methods to resursively unArrayify Array, i resolve my runtime type reification problem. Now i can compare equality between `Array[double]` with `Array[Double]`.

```
  // Convert unknow A en Array[T], so you need to call get with Type :
  // example : get[Array[Double](myVariable)
  // return an Array[Double] only if it's possible for this Variable, else it return None
  def get[T](variable: Variable[A])(implicit m: Manifest[T]): Option[T] = {
    if (ClassUtils.assignable(variable.prototype.`type`.runtimeClass, m.runtimeClass)) {
      val casted = variable.prototype.`type`.runtimeClass.cast(variable.value)
      Some(casted.asInstanceOf[T])
    } else {
      None
    }
```

I hope these methods can help other people :)

You can see helping method `ClassUtils.assignable` here :

https://gist.github.com/4686167

and on the source forge project :

https://forge.iscpif.fr/projects/openmole/repository/revisions/master/entry/core/openmole/misc/org.openmole.misc.tools/src/main/scala/org/openmole/misc/tools/obj/ClassUtils.scala

Answer (score 1):

This started out as a comment, since it's not an answer, but it's too big and needs formatting (plus my browser tab's auto-reload caused it to be lost the first time...)

So... For starters, your snippet of code is incomplete and / or incorrect. Potentially there are imports in effect which could alter the meaning of that code. Secondly, as shown it would not compile 'cause what appears to be a formal type parameter, the `A` has no binding. Thus unless you have an actual type named `A` that won't compile.

Secondly, `Double` is potentially ambiguous. There is both `scala.Double` and `java.lang.Double` and they are distinct. Scala auto-boxes and -unboxes primitive types for you, typically when they're used to instantiate type parameters for generic methods (and specialization is not used). A consequence of this is that `Array[scala.Double]` is distinct from `Array[java.lang.Double]`. Scala will create arrays of primitive types when possible, but `Array[java.lang.Double]` is explicitly an array of boxed double-precision floating point.

E.g.:

```
scala> val d1: scala.Double = 123.456
d1: Double = 123.456

scala> val d2: java.lang.Double = 234.567
d2: Double = 234.567

scala> d1.getClass
res25: Class[Double] = double

scala> d2.getClass
res26: Class[_ <: Double] = class java.lang.Double

scala> val ad1: Array[scala.Double] = Array(123.456, 234.567)
ad1: Array[Double] = Array(123.456, 234.567)

scala> val ad2: Array[java.lang.Double] = Array(234.567, 345.678)
ad2: Array[Double] = Array(234.567, 345.678)

scala> ad1.getClass
res27: Class[_ <: Array[Double]] = class [D

scala> ad2.getClass
res28: Class[_ <: Array[Double]] = class [Ljava.lang.Double;
```

So please, if you would, fill in the missing details of your sample code?

Comment: Thanks for answer, i update my code, i hope now this is a better question

Comment: With help of colleague, i find answer to my problem, i hope the answer can help other peoples :) Also, Thanks a lot for your enlightment.