# scala : Match type argument for an object

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

if i have a class that accepts a Type argument for example `Seq[T]` , and i've many objects of this class. and i want to split them depending on type Argument `T`

for example :

```
val x = List(Seq[Int](1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0),Seq[String]("a","b","c"))
x.foreach { a => 
  a match{ 
    case _ : Seq[String] => print("String") 
    case _ : Seq[Int] => print("Int")  
   }
 }
```

the result of this code is  `StringString`.
it only matches the class `Seq` not the Type also , what should i do to force it to match the Type ?

Answer (score 5):

What you're seeing happens due to Type Erasure (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html), some IDEs can warn you for errors like these.

You could have a look at Manifests, for example check out [What is a Manifest in Scala and when do you need it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3213510/what-is-a-manifest-in-scala-and-when-do-you-need-it)

Edit: like Patryk said, TypeTag replaced Manifest in Scala 2.10, see [Scala: What is a TypeTag and how do I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12218641/scala-2-10-what-is-a-typetag-and-how-do-i-use-it)

Comment: I guess more up to date information would be about [`TypeTags` and their usage](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12218641/1180426) instead.:)

Comment: Interesting, hadn't heard of that yet! I'll update my link to point to that.

Comment: I can give some links too: Scala reflection http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/overview.html 

You need heterogeneous lists here. For type-level programming there (in your case) is an awesome library: https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless , you can find there lots of interesting structures.

Comment: Oh god! You don't **need** to use type-level programming, but you definitely **can**. Shapeless is like BFG9000, both should be used when you completely understand consequences.

Answer (score 5):

**TypeTag Approach**

The Java runtime requires generic type param erasure.  Scala compiler combats this by 'injecting' type info into methods declared with `TypeTag` type arg:

```
def typeAwareMethod[T: TypeTag] (someArg: T) { 
  ... // logic referring to T, the type of varToCheck
}
```

(alternatively, can use an equivalent, more long-winded implicit param - not shown)

When scala compiles an invocation of a method having (1) type arg `[T: TypeTag]` and (2) normal arg  `someArg: T`, it collects type param metadata for `someArg` from the calling context and augments the type arg `T` with this metadata.   T's value plus tag data are externaly type-inferred from calls:

```
val slimesters = List[Reptile](new Frog(...), new CreatureFromBlackLagoon(...))
typeAwareMethod(slimesters)
```

**Logic Referring to T (within above method)** - runtime reflection

`import scala.reflection.runtime.universe._` : contents of the universe object of type `scala.relection.api.JavaUniverse`.  NB: subject to evolutionary API change

1. Direct `TypeTag` comparison:
   The tag info can be obtained via method `typeTag[T]`, then directly tested/pattern matched for (exact) equality with other type tags:

   ```
   val tag: TypeTag[T] = typeTag[T]

   if (typeTag[T] == typeTag[List[Reptile]]) ...

   typeTag[T] match {
     case typeTag[List[Reptile]] => ...
   }
   ```

   Limitations: not subtype aware (above won't match `List[Frog]`); no additional metadata obtainable through `TypeTag`.
2. Smarter Type-comparison operations:

   Convert to `Type` via `typeOf[T]` (or `typeTag[T].tpe`). Then use the gammut of `Type` ops, including pattern-matching.  NB: in reflection typespace, `=:=` means type equivalance (analogue of `:`), `<:<` means type conformance (analogue of `<:`)

   ```
   val tType: Type = typeOf[T] // or equivalently, typeTag[T].tpe

   if (typeOf[T] <:< typeOf[List[Reptile]]) ...  // matches List[Frog]

   typeOf[T] match {
     case t if t <:< typeOf[List[Reptile]] => ...
   }

   // Running Example:
   def testTypeMatch[T: TypeTag](t: T) = if (typeOf[T] <:< typeOf[Seq[Int]]) "yep!!!"

   test(List[Int](1, 2, 3))  // prints yep!!!
   ```

   Method still needs type param [T: TypeTag] or you'll get the type-erasure view of the world...
3. Introspect on Type metadata

   I lied in 2 ;).  For your case, `typeOf[T]` actually returns `TypeRef` (a subtype of `Type`), since you're instantiating a type declared elsewhere.  To get at the full metadata, you need to convert `Type` to `TypeRef`.

   ```
   typeTag[T].tpe match {
     case t: TypeRef => ... // call t.args to access typeArgs (as List[Type])
     case _ => throw IllegalArgumentException("Not a TypeRef")
   }
   ```

   - instead of `t: TypeRef`, can extract parts via pattern match on:

     ```
       case TypeRef(prefixType, typeSymbol, typeArgsListOfType) =>
     ```
   - `Type` has method:

     ```
     def typeSymbol: Symbol
     ```
   - Symbol has methods:

     ```
     def fullName: String
     def name: Name
     ```
   - Name has methods:

     ```
     def decoded: String  // the scala name
     def encoded: String  // the java name
     ```

**Solution For Your Case**

Solution based on (3):

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

def typeArgsOf[T: TypeTag](a: T): List[Type] = typeOf[T] match {
  case TypeRef(_, _, args) => args
  case _ => Nil
}

val a = Seq[Int](1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0)
val b = Seq[String]("a","b","c")
// mkString & pring for debugging - parsing logic should use args, not strings!
print("[" + (typeArgsOf(a) mkString ",") + "]")
print("[" + (typeArgsOf(b) mkString ",") + "]")
```

---

**Aside:** there's an issue with this test case:

```
val x = List(Seq[Int](1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0),Seq[String]("a","b","c"))
```

Type of x is List[Seq[Any]].  Any is the lowest common ancestor of String and Int.  In this case there's nothing to introspect, since all types descend from Any , and there's no further type information available.  To get stronger typing, separate the two Seqs, either via separate variables or a tuple/pair - but once separated, no higher order common mapping / folding across the two.  "Real world" cases shouldn't have this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would argue it's equally sensible to `def` the logic with multiple prototypes one per sequence type, than go into those type-erasure workarounds. The 2.10 compiler doesn't warn about type erasure, and at runtime it seems to work well in my case.

Presumably this avoids the problem, producing more intelligible code.