# Match parameterized type using Scala's pattern matching

Tags: scala, generics, types, pattern-matching

I have a `class Operator[T: TypeTag : ClassTag]` and in of it's methods, I want to use Scala's pattern matching on the parameterized type `T`. I know how pattern matching works and so tried the following in Scala's repl and got an error.

```
scala> def matchTest() = T match {
     | case x: String => "abcd"
     | case _ => null
     | }
<console>:11: error: not found: value T
       def matchTest() = T match {
                            ^
```

Comment: maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20125975/scala-match-type-argument-for-an-object

Comment: @RadoBuransky: I did add `TypeTag` and `ClassTag` just for tackling type erasure.

Answer (score 5):

`T` is a type, not a value. You can only match on values.

You can get an `implicitly[ClassTag[T]]` or `implicitly[TypeTag[T]]`, which are values, and do matching on those.

Comment: And `classTag[T]` and `typeTag[T]` are shorthands for these. :)

Comment: Can you give me full example, I still get some error on doing `def matchTest[T: TypeTag: ClassTag]() = typeTag[T] match {
      case typeTag[String] => "abcd"
      case _ => null
      }`

Comment: @KamalBanga Because you can call functions on a case matching. Assign `typeTag[String]` to a variable first, and then match on that.