# Why does List[String] is matched for List[Int] in my example though I pass Manifest?

Tags: scala, jvm

```
object Main extends App {
  def foo[A](somelist: List[A])(implicit m: Manifest[A]): String = somelist match {
    case _ : List[Int] => "we have a list of int!"
    case _ => "have no idea what this list is"
  }
}
Main.foo(List[String]("somestring"))
```

results in:

```
res0: String = we have a list of int!
```

I was sure the whole purpose of `Manifest` was to pass information to the `JVM` why doesnt this work? (PS I'm aware `TypeTag` is the updated way to do it I want to try it with `Manifest`).

thanks

Comment: Don't you get a compiler warning about erasure on line `case _: List[Int] =>`?

Comment: I do get `Warning:(5, 14) non-variable type argument Int in type pattern List[Int] (the underlying of List[Int]) is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure
    case _ : List[Int] => "we have a list of int!"
             ^` wasn't the Manifest supposed to fix that?

Comment: No it cannot be fixed in this way. Type pattern in general should be avoided. You can try `case (_: Int) :: _ => ???`

Comment: i'm doing this to practice `Manifest` and to understand what it is not for real world programming.  I get it if i want to access the type which I pass in `List[A]` then I need to check it in `m` and not in `somelist`

Comment: but `case (_: Int) ` checks if the `somelist` is `Int` its never `Int` its always a list of something isn't it?

Comment: It checks whether the list start with an `Int`, assuming the element type is coherent (not a naughty `List[Any]`)

Answer (score 1):

The only use of `Manifest[A]` in pattern-matching is to allow you to match against `A`:

```
somelist match {
  case _: A => ...
  case _ => ...
}
```

not against any type you want to.

Comment: in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3213510/what-is-a-manifest-in-scala-and-when-do-you-need-it he is checking if `manifest` is of type `manifest[String]` why couldn't i also compare to `Manifest[String]`? isn't the whole purpose of `Manifest` to store the type to have it available in runtime?

Comment: in the post he is doing: `(implicit m: Manifest[T]) = {
    if (m <:< manifest[String])`

Comment: You can. Matching against `_: List[Int]` doesn't do this for you (it would actually be incorrect if it did: consider `foo(List[String]())`).

Answer (score 1):

as it turns out there is a `Predef` `manifest` definition so you should compare the `m` only to this predef manifest in the following way

```
object Main extends App {
  println(Main.foo(List[String]("fkdjfkdj")))

  def foo[A](somelist: List[A])(implicit m: Manifest[A]): String = {
    if (m <:< manifest[String]) {
      "its a string"
    } else {
      "its not a string"
    }
  }
}
```

which yields correctly:

"its a string"

and for int

```
object Main extends App {
  println(Main.foo(List[Int](1)))

  def foo[A](somelist: List[A])(implicit m: Manifest[A]): String = {
    if (m <:< manifest[String]) {
      "its a string"
    } else {
      "its not a string"
    }
  }
}

its not a string
```