# What is ClassManifest in Scala?

Tags: scala

I am new to Scala and I was learning "context bound" from posts. But I found many of those are explaining "context bound" using ClassManifest as example. For instance,

```
def tabulate[T](len: Int, f: Int => T)(implicit m: ClassManifest[T]) = {
    val xs = new Array[T](len)
    for (i <- 0 until len) xs(i) = f(i)
    xs
}
```

I find it weird that the implicit parameter `m` is required but never used in the function body. Thus I would like to know what ClassManifest is and what its relationship is with context bound. Thanks!

**EDIT:**

I have seen [What is a Manifest in Scala and when do you need it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3213510/what-is-a-manifest-in-scala-and-when-do-you-need-it) before, but it's asking for `Manifest` not `ClassManifest`, and there is no explanation regarding `ClassManifest` in that post, thus I ask this similar (but, IMO, not duplicate) question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Manifest in Scala and when do you need it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3213510/what-is-a-manifest-in-scala-and-when-do-you-need-it)

Comment: @manojlds Sorry I am new to Scala, but is `Manifest` the same thing as `ClassManifest`? Thanks

Comment: please note that both are deprecated

Answer (score 3):

You can find explanation about `ClassManifest` for old scala versions (before 2.10) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3213510/what-is-a-manifest-in-scala-and-when-do-you-need-it). Please, read all answers, [some of them explain not only `Manifest` but `ClassManifest` too](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3213862/1809978):

> There exists also a weaker form named ClassManifest which can be
>   constructed from knowing just the top-level class of a type, without
>   necessarily knowing all its argument types.

In Scala 2.11.8, 2.12-M4 `ClassManifest` is deprecated and became an [alias to `ClassTag`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.0-M4/scala/reflect/index.html#ClassManifest[T]=scala.reflect.ClassTag[T]) :

```
type  ClassManifest[T] = ClassTag[T]
```

It's deprecated since 2.10.0.

P.S. Actually [this post](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/context-and-view-bounds.html) from scala documentation that you probably read **is completely outdated**, even the view bounds (`<%`) described there are [deprecated too](https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/2909) (for a quite long time) so you should avoid them as well ([using this simple trick if you really need them, but implicit views are not recommended in any form](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/scala-internals/hNow9MvAi6Q/HgrjWDaF1mIJ))