# In Scala, How can Manifest implicitly be caputured in context?

Tags: scala, jvm, manifest

```
def getManifest[T : Manifest] = implicitly[Manifest[T]]

class A[T] 
object A {
    def apply[T] = new A[T]
} 
def getA[T : A] = implicitly[A[T]] 

val m = getManifest[Int] 
//res0: Manifest[Int] = Int

val a = getA[Int]
//<console>:14: error: could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type A[Int]
```

Even though there is no implicit variable in context

by calling `getManifest[Int]`, `m` of type `Manifest[Int]` is caputred implicitly

However my custom class A, `getA[Int]` emits an error

Because there is no implicit variable in cotext.

What is the difference between class A and Manifest

does Scala compiler knows about Manifest and do some magic ???

like, creating some implicit variables for Manifest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer is yes. `Manifest`s are compiler magic where the Scala compiler will automatically conjure up implicit instances of them for types as they are needed. They're used to get around type erasure on the JVM (the problem that at runtime generic types get erased so for example a `List[Int]` looks the same as a `List[String]`).

See [What is a Manifest in Scala and when do you need it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3213510/what-is-a-manifest-in-scala-and-when-do-you-need-it) for more details.

They are also deprecated now in favor of [`TypeTag`s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12218641/scala-what-is-a-typetag-and-how-do-i-use-it).

Comment: Thanks, your answer is very helpful.
 is it possible to make my custom class A to act like Manifest ?

Comment: Some uses should be replaced by `TypeTag`s, other by `ClassTag`s.

Comment: @WonpyoPark, no, although there's a chance implicit conversions will probably get you what you want. In particular, you're going to need to tell the compiler how to get an `A` from any type `T` and one way of doing that is via implicit conversions.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov purely out of curiosity, have you run into any cases in the wild where `TypeTag` wouldn't do and you chose `ClassTag` instead?

Comment: @badcook Probably the most common one is matching `case x: A` (where `A` is a type parameter). It works when you have a `ClassTag[A]` in scope, but not with a `TypeTag[A]`. Also you often need a `ClassTag` to work with arrays.