# Why can't I create an array of generic type?

Tags: arrays, scala

This does not work:

```
def giveArray[T](elem:T):Array[T] = {
    new Array[T](1)
  }
```

But this does:

```
  def giveList[T](elem:T):List[T] = {
    List.empty[T]
  }
```

I am sure this is a pretty basic thing and I know that Arrays can behave a bit unusual in Scala.

Could someone explain to me how to create such an Array and also why it doesn't work in the first place?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is due to JVM type erasure. Manifest were introduce to handle this, they cause type information to be attached to the type T. This will compile:

```
def giveArray[T: Manifest](elem:T):Array[T] = {
  new Array[T](1)
}
```

There are nearly duplicated questions on this. Let me see if I can dig up.
See http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections_38.html for more details. I quote (replace evenElems with elem in your case)

> *What's required here is that you help the compiler out by providing some runtime hint what the actual type parameter of evenElems is*

In particular you can also use `ClassManifest`.

```
def giveArray[T: ClassManifest](elem:T):Array[T] = {
  new Array[T](1)
}
```

Similar questions:

- [cannot find class manifest for element type T](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2252641/cannot-find-class-manifest-for-element-type-t)
- [What is a Manifest in Scala and when do you need it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3213510/what-is-a-manifest-in-scala-and-when-do-you-need-it)
- [About Scala generics: cannot find class manifest for element type T](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3474073/about-scala-generics-cannot-find-class-manifest-for-element-type-t)

Comment: I assumed it was asked many times before but I couldn't find anything. Thanks for answering it again :)

Comment: Oh I never answered this one before. I asked the same question a while back :) I think in this case you would have eventually stumbled on it if you searched with "scala" and the error message.

Comment: To be more precise, this is because `T` is erased but arrays _are not_. Of note too, `ClassManifest` is faster.

Comment: Also, Java does not have this problem because you can't pass primitives as generics in java, whereas you can in Scala. In other words, you can't create an `Array<T> giveArray<T>` in Java that returns `Array<int>`, but `giveArray[T]` in Scala can. I think this is an important point to make.